# ADO.Net vs ADO Record Locking

Tags: ado.net, ado

I'm struggling to understand the differences between ADO and ADO.NET.

ADO "Classic" has different lock levels... I'm wondering now, what is the default lock level for ADO.NET? How would I open a connection as Batch Lock or Read Only.

What is the default behavior of ADO.NET? What sort of lock does it place on a MSSQL database when doing a .fill().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO.net uses an optimistic locking concurrency by default but you also have to look at what is happening on the SQL server.

Unless you specify a hint such as NoLock a shared lock will be issued. This is a lightweight lock that allows other transactions to read a resource but no other transactions to modify the data. This lock is released after the data is finished being read